# how to separate header and cpp file cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to set up a chat app project and it looks like this:

[project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot3Ai.png)

I've found some tutorials, but I cant find out how to set up this How would the CMakeLists.txt files look?

P.S. Maybe I'm not doing the project folder hierarchy correctly. Could you then tell me how to do it better?

Comment: Textual descriptions are often better than "look at this picture and hopefully you'll see the same thing I do". Try describing your problem in words so we can focus on exactly the problem you are currently experiencing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To he honest, I haven't got you structure well but answering you question - this is how you make your files executable in `CMakeList.txt`
[image]

What about including headers in source files, you can do it 2 ways:

1. Include header by relative path, e.g. `#include "../../include/client/client.h"`
   What doesn't look good
2. Include header by absolute path adding include directories in CMakeList.txt `include_directories(./include/client)` and `include_directories(./include/server)`

Note that you can write only 1 path in `include_directories()` unlike you could write multiple paths in `add_executable()`.

After performing such action you can simple include your header into source files by `#include "client.h"` in `client.cpp` and `#include "server.h"` respectively.

See more in [Quick CMake tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#link-libs) chapter 5.

Also you should know the difference between `" "` and `<>`. I'd refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: Hey, thank u for your answer. It is work for me. But, i need write it: #include "../../include/client/client.h" to include file. Can i fix it? Or i should do it library?

Comment: Please note, that Stack Overflow **discourages** using **images of code** both in a question and in an answer.

Comment: @trytobecomebetter you can write relative path, exactly as you mentioned before but there is other way (seems better to me) - adding include directories. I will edit my answer with screenshot